# Android Content Provider - how to check columns for multiple tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 2 tables in my sqlite database so now I'm trying to create content provider for the database. all of the examples i've seen so far only shows the CRUD code for 2 tables but not checkColumns. I tried doing this

```
private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {

    if (Constants.COLUMNS != null) {
        HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
        HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(Constants.COLUMNS));
        if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
        }
    }
    if (Constants.pCOLUMNS != null) {
        HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
        HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(Constants.pCOLUMNS));
        if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
        }
    }
}
```

then for the query, I did this

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    checkColumns(Constants.COLUMNS);
    checkColumns(Constants.pCOLUMNS);
    queryBuilder.setTables(Constants.ITEM_TABLE);
    queryBuilder.setTables(Constants.PANTRY_TABLE);

    int type = URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
    switch (type) {
        case ITEMS:
            break;
        case ITEM:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(Constants.COLUMN_iID + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        case sPANTRY:
            break;
        case PANTRY:
            queryBuilder.appendWhere(Constants.COLUMN_pID + " = " + uri.getLastPathSegment());
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return cursor;
}
```

from Constants.java

```
public static final String[] COLUMNS = {
        Constants.COLUMN_iID,
        Constants.COLUMN_ITEM,
        Constants.COLUMN_iQUANTITY,
        Constants.COLUMN_iUNIT,
        Constants.COLUMN_PRICE,
        Constants.COLUMN_STORE

};

public static final String[] pCOLUMNS = {
        Constants.COLUMN_pID,
        Constants.COLUMN_PANTRY,
        Constants.COLUMN_pQUANTITY,
        Constants.COLUMN_pUNIT,
        Constants.COLUMN_EXPIRY_DATE
};
}
```

but I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown columns in projection
```

I tried using switch case instead in checkColumns like this

```
private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
    switch(projection) {
        case Constants.COLUMNS:
            HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
            HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(Constants.COLUMNS));
            if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
            }
            break;
        case Constants.pCOLUMNS:
            HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
            HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(Constants.pCOLUMNS));
            if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
            }
           break;
    }
}
```

but I get 'constant expression required' on both Constants.

Answer (score 0):

You get the "constant expression required" error because the `checkColumns(String[] projection)` method takes a string array, and the switch statement cannot use string array as the "switch" variable.

The first approach seems OK. You get the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` probably because the there is a mismatch in the `requestedColumns` and `availableColumns` (e.g. a requested column does not exist in the available columns).

Assuming the logic is to check if all the projection columns are in the items and pantry columns, then you could add the Constants.COLUMNS and Constants.pCOLUMNS into one array (say "totalColumns"), then do the check:

```
private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
    if (projection != null) {
        String[] totalColumns = ArrayUtils.addAll(Constants.COLUMNS, Constants.pCOLUMNS);
        if (!totalColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column projection");
    }
}
```

(Note that you need to import ArrayUtils, or you can write your own if you don't want to import it..., anyway, you get the point).

Comment: What do you mean? Idk if this will help but the code works fine if it's only 1 table.

Comment: Assuming the logic is to check if all the projection columns are in the items and pantry columns, then the original checkColumns() logic is wrong. I updated the answer based on this assumption.